# Is there any way for the Evangelical Union Event to not fire even when there is a Protestant Elector?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I've been playing an eu4 game in ironman mode as Brandenburg. I've become Protestant in order to form Prussia, however, I also have toyed with the possibility of becoming Emperor. In order for me to do this, of course, I need the Protestant side to win/tie the league war. But despite the fact that both I and the Palatinate are Protestant Electors, the league interface has not appeared on the HRE screen. That *is* where it appears, right? Is there any way this could have happened, or is eu4 just being buggy?

Edit: Oh, and I should add that the Palatinate has been an elector for over 20 years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should trigger eventually. It can only trigger after 1550 and if the Counter-Reformation has kicked off. It's an event that happens to the emperor, and has the following trigger:

```
trigger = {
    has_dlc = "Art of War"
    NOT = { has_global_flag = evangelical_union_happened }
    hre_leagues_enabled = no
    hre_religion_locked = no
    hre_religion_treaty = no
    is_emperor = yes        
    is_year = 1550
    religion = catholic
    has_global_flag = counter_reformation
    any_known_country = {
        is_elector = yes
        religion = protestant
        is_subject = no
    }
    NOT = { hre_reform_level = 6 }
}
```

Assuming the HRE hasn't reformed to level 6 yet, it just has a 120 month mean-time-to-happen. It gets more likely if it still hasn't fired at 1575, and even more so at 1600. So; it'll happen eventually.